# How to get compressed file data from a ZIP file in Java?

Tags: java, zip

Using `java.util.zip`, I can reach the uncompressed files (which is the normal, expected behavior). I can also reach the metadata about each file (via `java.util.zip.ZipFile`) Is there a way to actually get the compressed data (byte stream) of a file within a ZIP, that is,  before Java uncompresses it? Similarly, is there any libraries for lower level ZIP operations for Java?

EDIT: Obviously, I can do this by reading through the ZIP file as a byte stream and interpreting the whole file but that would involve tons of complications about Zip file. Essentially, this would mean creating a library from scratch for reading/handling zip files. I don't want that.

Comment: A zip file is not a folder. It is just one file that contains metadata for each compressed file. The metadata itself means nothing outside the context of compression.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree. Still, I can traverse through a zip file using Enumerator and would get a `java.util.zip.ZipEntry`, right? I can call `getName()` or get `getTime()`, etc methods on this. Similarly, by putting giving this `ZipEntry` as a parameter to `java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream()`, I'd get an input stream of the _uncompressed_ data. What I want is not uncompressed, but the compressed data, just as it exists in the raw Zip file.

Comment: A `ZipEntry` is the metadata I was talking about. Compression is just taking the byte content and making it smaller. Alone, you would lose file name, file time, permissions, etc.. All that information is stored as metadata (you would have to look at the zip algorithm) in a ZipEntry. But the zip entry is not a file on which you can open an `InputStream`. If you really want to compressed data, you need to read the ZIP algorithm to know how it is managed, byte positions in headers, flags, etc. and parse the zip file yourself

Comment: I totally agree, we're on the same page = ) I need metadata as well, but I ALSO need the compressed data (as it appears in the raw Zip file, before getting uncompressed by Java)

Comment: I've deleted my answer as apparently it's unhelpful, but you really need to give more information about what you're trying to do. There may well be alternative approaches which would be more useful.

Comment: @kolistivra What I'm trying to say is you can't with the zip package. You most likely need to do it yourself. ZIP is a file format. You need to know how to decode it to get specific subsets of its content/byte stream.

Comment: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure) - this gives all the sizes of headers etc.. You need to read the headers then the file bytes.

Comment: @bmorris591 I've gone through that and a bunch of other documents on Zip internals today already, thanks for mentioning though. [This link](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) is the official documentation by the way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe so; I'll end up decoding the whole file by myself. It can be done by changing 1 line in Java's standard library code, actually.

Comment: Good stuff. Give it a go; when you encounter a problem then post your code and describe the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't talk about my direct use case, unfortunately. I need this for experimenting about some kind of a patching application.

Comment: @kolistivra If that is true, it's legit .

Comment: It is fairly easy to crack the ZIP file format.  The hard part is the compression/decompression.